How can I display email message headers for all messages?
I am trying to check whether an email that I sent has read-receipt enabled.  According to this Q&A, I can search for Disposition-Notification-To in the headers.  I've been able to view the headers for some messages using the following procedure:

Click the 3 dots at the upper right corner of the message
In the resulting popup menu, click View
In the resulting popup submenu, click View message details

For some messages sent by me, this shows the headers in a popup window.  For others, the popup window is blank.  It doesn't seem to depend on whether the message has an attachment.
Based on limited experimentation, it seems that messages that I CC to myself contain message headers. Messages that I don't CC myself do not.
Why doesn't this show the headers for all messages?
Do I need to CC myself on all messages to see the headers?

Please [edit] your question to include what messages specifically you are comparing. For example, are you comparing the headers for messages you receive from yourself (eg CC) to messages you receive from others? Apples to Apples. Or, are you comparing messages you receive from yourself (eg. CC) to messages you "send" to others?  Apples to Oranges. If the latter, only the 1st message was delivered and includes headers. The outgoing message was not received, and therefore would have no "travel history"

I believe that the answer that I posted does constitute an answer.  The reason why I don't see headers for all messages is because (it empirically seems) that only messages that are delivered to me have headers, e.g., via CC.  Messages that aren't delivered to me, i.e., which I fish out of the Sent folder, do not.  If appropriate, I can revise my answer to be clearer about this, but at the moment, it is deleted. I didn't include these details in the original question because I had no idea that they were the determining factors. Therefore, I don't think they should be added to the question.
